# Django query with contains and keywords

Tags: python, django

I have some keywords in one string splitted with " ". I have also table with column name. How can I get all records which will have in name part of one keyword?

Example:

keywords = 'test split el'
And if I have in records 'test2' 'element' and 'show' the query should return 'test2' and 'element'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Table.objects.filter(name__in=keyword.split(' '))
```

OK, that was wrong. I don't know, if this can be accomplished in a one liner or single sql query. The more obvious way is like this, but I don't know, if this is optimal:

```
result = []
for keyword in keywords.split(' '):
    result += list(Table.objects.filter(name__icontains=keyword))
```

Ok, this can be done in a single query, but I am not exactly sure how. You can try this:

```
   final_pred = Q()
   for pred in [Q(name__icontains=keyword) for keyword in keywords.split(' ')]:
     final_pred = final_pred | pred;
   Table.objects.filter(final_pre)
```

Comment: The problem is that I will make as many queries as many keywords I will have. What do you think about get all records from table and add to result list filtered record?

Comment: I have added additional explanation with a single query.